# Calling StateHasChanged() every second is optimal in blazor web assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a `blazor webassembly` app. I have the requirement to show current `DateTime` in my app. Here is how I achieved my requirement with pure `C#`.

```
@using System.Threading

<p>@CurrentDateTime</p>

@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            new Timer(DateTimeCallback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }

    private void DateTimeCallback(object state)
    {
        CurrentDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

This gives the exact current time and gets updated every second. But I'm little bit worried on calling `StateHasChanged()` every second. Does it impact performance in long run? or I need to fallback to `javascript` to achieve this functionality? Please suggest your inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I'm little bit worried on calling StateHasChanged() every second.

Don't be. Every millisecond might be a problem, every second should be fine.

Some improvements:

1. System.Threading.Timer is IDisposable. You should implement the Dispose logic in this Page.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513110/60761).
2. You should make the callback an `async void` and then `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`
   This makes no difference in WebAssembly at the moment, but one day Blazor/Wasm will get real Threads and then your code will fail. InvokeAsync() is already required for Blazor/server.

Comment: Is there any reason to go for `async void` instead of `async Task`?

Comment: The timer doesn't support `async Task`. So use either an `async void` (Ok-ish for events) or do __not__ `await` the  InvokeAsync(). Whatever.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion, in Microsoft's docs, see [Receiving a call from something external to the Blazor rendering and event handling system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-7.0#receiving-a-call-from-something-external-to-the-blazor-rendering-and-event-handling-system).